# Song 2 by Mr Physicson

Tags: wordplay, music

Tonight, My Physicson noticed his little son was down with the blues. So, he started singing:

> Iteratively provide power to this implement so, as predicted by the
>   third law, you begin to propulse your vehicle on the surface
>
> Maintain an optimum ratio of power and  minimization of disturbance,
>   all the while keeping the propulsion vector parallel to your
>   encompassing fluid's one
>
> Indulge yourself to find hapiness from the harmony generated by the
>   whole motion,
>
> which can lead in a philosophical introspection of existence in a
>   sweet manner.

A smile appeared in the young kid's face.

**What was Mr. Physicson singing?**

Note: Nothing to do with Blur.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure, but is it:

> Row your boat
> Row, row, row your boat.
> Gently down the stream,
> Merrily merrily, merrily, merrily.
> Life is but a dream.